# calculate the average depth of a binary search tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, stack-overflow

So i need to calculate the average depth of a BST and i have this function in my class BST

```
int totalDepth(Node node, int depth) 
{
    if(node == null) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return depth                              // myself
     + totalDepth(node.left, depth + 1)   // my left subtree
     + totalDepth(node.right, depth + 1); // my right subtree
}
```

But when i try to print the result in main like this:

```
System.out.println("Average Depth : "+tree.totalDepth(tree.root,0)/10000);
```

I get a stackoverflow error

Please help me

Comment: Put lots of debug in. Start with some at the beginning of the function showing something about the current node. Separate the return expression so you can put a debug print just before the call with `node.left` and again just before the one with `node.right`. This should show why it is spiralling. It might be useful to post the code that shows how you create `tree`.

Comment: How many nodes are in the tree? Also, was the tree robustly constructed, i.e. no circular references?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you think you're traversing your binary tree but you're stuck calling `totalDepth` on the same nodes continuously until the JVM runs out of memory to use.

I suggest you add print statements or logging into your `totalDepth` method to see how deep you're traversing your binary tree or if you're traversing it at all. I'm assuming the `if (node == null)` never evaluates to true so the call stack goes on until you run out of memory.